# Unable to make collapsible work on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm attempting to made a collapsible (and hopefully simple) DIV and was working with another answer I had found here on stack overflow but I cannot seem to get it to work on my website. I do have a fiddle with the full links and coding which shows that its actually working (in the fiddle) but then I input the code into my page and it hides the stuff beneath the first picture (using that as the divider) but when I click on it nothing happens (it doesn't display)

Below is the snippet of HTML coding:

```
<p class="expand-one"><a href="#"></a> <img src="https://www.mywebsite.net/something/vip1.png"></p>
<p class="content-one">
<td width="33%" align="center" valign="top">
<br>
</td>
<td width="33%" align="center" valign="top">
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.net/bigslice" title="The Big Slice: Home of the Edge">
<font color="#dace77">[ m u s i c ]</font>
</a><br>
<font color="#FAF9B6">$ROOMNAME bigslice$</font><br>$USERLIST bigslice$<br>
</td>
</tr>
</p>
```

and up in my CSS I have the simple addition of:

```
<style>p.content-one {
display: none;
}
</style>
```

And down before the body ends where all my JS scripts are I have

```
<script>
$('.expand-one').click(function() {
 $('.content-one').slideToggle('slow');
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm confused with what's going on in the table, typically a `<td>` would be nested immediately under a `<tr>` which is nested immediately under `<tbody>`, `<thead>` or `<table>`. I've not seen a `<td>` nested in a `<p>` before. Without that table stuff in there, it seems okay: https://jsfiddle.net/fvwyrm1e/

Comment: that's actually dang close. the reasoning for that is because they're 'chatroom's which are going to be nested in there (and are done inside of tables for spacing, etc) unless there's a simple way to get that spacing using this solution.

Comment: Not sure what your spacing looks like- do you have a link to your fiddle that looks the way you want and just doesn't behave the way you want? It's likely you could use grid layout or flexbox to get your spacing the way you want without HTML tables, or a library like Bootstrap to make those solutions even easier.

Comment: This is the link to my original fiddle with the TD coding in there for spacing and it works in the preview but not when I input it on my site which makes me feel like I'm missing something easy or its conflicting elsewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/L54j7xa2/1/

Comment: If it works the way you want in the fiddle, but not your site, I can only speculate- are you including jQuery before your code snippet? Are there any errors in the browser console? Does the JS code from your snippet come after the HTML with the `.expand-one` element(s)? Is the `.expand-one` element generated after the page loads? If you add a `console.log('test')` in the click listener, does it log? If you try `.remove()` instead of `slideToggle()`, does the `.content-one` element disappear from the HTML in your dev tools?

Comment: You sir, nailed it. I'd like to promote your answer. I didn't have the Jquery loading before everything else in the head (but at the bottom) I had them backwards. Oye. Thank you Mark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer was as simple as jQuery not loading before the code using it, I thought I'd post the troubleshooting steps I suggested as an answer. The question may be marked as a duplicate, but if not, maybe someone will stumble upon it and be helped... idk.

1. Ensure any code using jQuery is added after the jQuery library is included (typically I include jQuery at the end of the body and any custom script after that, but that's personal preference).
2. Check the brower console (F12) for errors- typically these are easy to grok, or you can search for the error message.
3. If jQuery attempts to select an element before the element is added (either because the jQuery comes before the HTML code, or because the HTML code is dynamically added after loading), it won't find an element- thus adding a listener won't do anything. Either ensure the code comes after the element, attach the listener to a parent/ancestor and specify which element to listen for (e.g. `$(document).on('click', 'p', function() { /*...*/ })` will attach a listener to the entire document which will only run when a paragraph is clicked), or use `$(function() { /* code here */ })` to ensure your code doesn't run until the page is done loading.
4. `console.log()` is extremely helpful if you're not sure if code just won't run, or if it's running and just not affecting anything. If nothing logs, the code isn't running.

Comment: Thank you Mark. It might be a duplicate but I know personally I'll reference this again when I run across it and learn more about debugging and checking the console (still new so I always forget). I couldn't be more thankful.